# Why Index (on primary key column) is not used?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key, between

I have a date table, which has a column `date` (PK). The `CREATE` script is here:

```
CREATE TABLE date_table (
  date                DATE
 ,year                INT(4)
 ,month               INT(2)
 ,day                 INT(2)
 ,month_pad           VARCHAR(2)
 ,day_pad             VARCHAR(2)
 ,month_name          VARCHAR(10)
 ,year_month_index    INT(6)
 ,year_month_hypname  VARCHAR(7)
 ,year_month_name     VARCHAR(15)
 ,week_day_index      INT(1)
 ,day_name            VARCHAR(9)
 ,week                INT(2)
 ,week_interval       VARCHAR(13)
 ,weekend_fl          INT(1)
 ,quarter_num         INT(1)
 ,quarter_num_pad     VARCHAR(2)
 ,quarter_name        VARCHAR(2)
 ,year_quarter_index  INT(6)
 ,year_quarter_name   VARCHAR(7)
 ,PRIMARY KEY (date)
);
```

Now I would like select rows from this table with dynamic values, using such as `LAST_DAY()` or `DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(),'%Y-01-01'), INTERVAL X YEAR)`, etc.

When one of my queries failed and didn't execute in 30 secs, I knew something was fishy, and it looks like the reason is that the index on the primary key column is not used. Here are my results (sorry for using an image instead of copying the queries, but I thought it's concise enough for this purpose, and the queries are short/simple enough):

[image]

First of all, it's strange that the `BETWEEN` works differently than using `>=` and `<=`. Secondly, it looks like the index is only used for constant values. If you look closely, you can see that on the right side (where `>=` and `<=` is used), it shows ~9K rows, which is half of the rows in the table (the table has about ~18k rows, dates from `2000-01-01` to `2050-12-31).

Comment: Does it make a difference if you store `LAST_DAY(SYSDATE())` in a variable and use that instead in the query?

Comment: Do you know what a primary key is?

Comment: date is a [reserved/key word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-D).  Perhaps the engine is getting confused.  either name the column differently or ensure to wrap it in backticks.

Comment: @Andrew: well, it works, but unfortunately I'm creating a model in SSDT for SSAS, and it looks like I can't use variables :(.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic: Well, I'm quite new, so my knowledge, but what is relevant now is that if a column is a primary key, it has an index too. Not really sure what are you referring to.

Comment: @xQbert: unfortunately it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic, why did you ask that?

Comment: Because an index a different concept than a primary key. A primary key cannot be "used", its only purpose is to prevent you from inserting inconsistent data.

Comment: I admit I asked the question in a very stupid way hence I edited the title (and a post a little bit). But let's move on and focus on the actual problem here.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic - In MySQL (unllike some other products), the `PRIMARY KEY` is unique, is an index, and is used for uniquely identifying each row for transactional purposes.  That is, the PK _can and will be_ uses as an index _if_ the Optimizer decides it is optimal.

Comment: That's why I asked, @MonkeySupersonic. The PK is also an index, so I don't see what's wrong with what Arklur posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if I use `CURRENT_DATE()` (or `NOW()`) instead of `SYSDATE()`, it's working. Both of these queries:

```
SELECT *
  FROM date_table t
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND t.ddate >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) AND t.ddate <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE());

SELECT *
  FROM date_table t
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND t.ddate >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) AND t.ddate <= LAST_DAY(NOW());
```

Give the same result, which is this:

[image]

I will accept my answer as a solution, but I'm still looking for an explanation. I thought it might has to do something with `SYSDATE()` not being a `DATE`, but `NOW()` is also not a `DATE`...

**EDIT:** Forgot to add, `BETWEEN` is also working as I see.

Comment: Aren't they all actually `DATETIME`? Or is any of those just `DATE`?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html - NOW() and SYSDATE() is DATETIME, but CURRENT_DATE() is just a DATE. I won't say I understand it (and you can't even cast SYSDATE() as DATE, it won't work), but...at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

> SYSDATE() returns the time at which it executes. This differs from the behavior for NOW(), which returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.)

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate

That is, the Optimizer does not see this as a "constant".  Otherwise, the Optimizer eagerly evaluates any "constant expressions", then tries to take advantage of knowing the value.

See also the `sysdate_is_now` option.

Bottom line:  Don't use `SYSDATE()` for normal datetime usage; use `NOW()` or `CURDATE()`.